# Order By Column Name in Union Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, union

I am trying to reference a column name inside of an ORDER BY. I'm stumped and pulling my hair out b/c I know I've done this before but I can't remember and I can't find the answer doing a search.

```
SELECT 2, LFEA_TYPE, LFEA_TITLE, LFEA_CHECKED, LFEA_VALUE, LFEA_PARAGRAPH FROM LFEA WHERE LFEA_LIS_ID = 230130 UNION SELECT 1, 'ACCOM', 'Air Conditioning', 'Y', LIS_AC_TEXT, NULL FROM LIS WHERE LIS_ID = 230130 ORDER BY 1 ASC, 2 ASC, 4 DESC, 5 DESC, CASE WHEN (LFEA_PARAGRAPH IS NOT NULL AND LFEA_PARAGRAPH <> '') THEN 2 ELSE 1 END ASC
```

This is a pretty basic query but I receive:

```
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator
```

If I remove the last ORDER BY element, it works:

```
SELECT 2, LFEA_TYPE, LFEA_TITLE, LFEA_CHECKED, LFEA_VALUE, LFEA_PARAGRAPH FROM LFEA WHERE LFEA_LIS_ID = 230130 UNION SELECT 1, 'ACCOM', 'Air Conditioning', 'Y', LIS_AC_TEXT, NULL FROM LIS WHERE LIS_ID = 230130 ORDER BY 1 ASC, 2 ASC, 4 DESC, 5 DESC
```

So it's a pretty good bet it's the LFEA_PARAGRAPH element causing the issue.

I understand from my experience (and the MSDN docs) that the column names you use in the ORDER BY should be the ones from the first query. So I am stumped why this isn't working as intended.

Comment: column names in the `order by` are only resolved to projected columns from the `SELECT` when they appear on their own. If they are involved in any kind of expression in the `ORDER BY` they are not resolved in this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work better if you wrap the `union` in a subquery, and order in the outer query?

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 2 as col1, LFEA_TYPE, LFEA_TITLE, LFEA_CHECKED, LFEA_VALUE, LFEA_PARAGRAPH FROM LFEA WHERE LFEA_LIS_ID = 230130 
    UNION ALL SELECT 1, 'ACCOM', 'Air Conditioning', 'Y', LIS_AC_TEXT, NULL FROM LIS WHERE LIS_ID = 230130 
) t
ORDER BY 1, 2, 4 DESC, 5 DESC, 
    CASE WHEN LFEA_PARAGRAPH IS NOT NULL AND LFEA_PARAGRAPH <> '' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END
```

Comment: It produces this error "No column name was specified for column 1 of 't'"

Comment: It makes sense that it would work the way you write the query, however, does it make sense that I can't use Column Names from the first UNIONed query in the ORDER BY?

Comment: @Nick: ah yes, you need an alias for the first column too. Fixed in the query.